# How to invoke methods in a required / correct sequence via reflection

Tags: java, selenium, reflection

I am new to java and selenium and trying to execute methods (tests) in class A from class B by using java reflections. The methods are being called and are also being executed. But the issue is that the methods are not being executed in the sequence they are written in class A or in a required sequence.

For eg. class A has following methods in sequence:

```
1. Login
2. Go to Page 1 --> do some activity
3. Go to Page 2 --> do some activity
4. Go to Page 4 --> do some activity
5. Logout
```

When these are called via reflection in class B, it changes the sequence to:

```
4. Go to Page 4 --> do some activity
2. Go to Page 1 --> do some activity
5. Logout
1. Login
2. Go to Page 1 --> do some activity
```

Due to this, the method fails since first step is to login and since the user is not logged in, the Go to Page 4 --> do some activity cannot be preformed.

How can I make the methods to be executed in the correct format. Is there  any naming format?

Class A:

```
    public void Login()  
        { 
            //Some action;
        }

        public void GoToHomepage() 
       {
          //Some action;
        }

        public void GotoPageOne(){
            //Some action;
        }


        public void GotoPageTow(){
            //Some action;
        }

        public void GotoPageThree(){
            //Some action;
        }

        public void GotoPagefour(){
            //Some action
        }
```

Class B (calling the methods from class A via reflections)

```
    public static void main (String args[]){
    public static Method[] method;
    ClassA wa = new ClassA(driver);
            method=wa.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
             for (int i=0;i<=method.length-1;i++){
             System.out.println(method[i].getName());
             method[i].invoke(wa);
```

The methods are printing in the same sequence in which they are executed.

Kindly suggest and also let me know if i am doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to call the methods with reflection?

Comment: I am working on data driven testing and want to execute only a specific set of test methods at runtime on some specific conditions. This is why I am using reflections....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--) the result array isn't sorted.
You could use `Collections.sort()` to sort them.

But in general it isn't a good idea to invoke them after their declaration order because it's not flexible at any time. Changing the source code in it's order would cause problems. Please change your approach.

Comment: I see your point and I dont want to change my code. I will try to use Collections.sort(). But on what basis are the methods sorted by reflection?

Comment: According to the documentation: The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order.

Comment: I would recommend you to implement something which lets you to invoke methods in a sequence, e.g. a service which invokes this methods in a particular way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sequential order just write a single method that will call all your methods with the order you want like this :

```
class TestA {

    private A aToTest = new A();

    public void callSequence() {
        aToTest.login();
        aToTest.goToHomePage();
        aToTest.goToPageOne();
        ...
    }
}

class B {
    public static void main (String args[]){
    public static Method[] method;
    Class<TesttA> clazz = TestA.class;
    method = clazz.getDelcareMethods();
    method[0].invoke();
}
```